# Index rebuilding best practices on Oracle range partitioned table

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

We have a range partitioned table and about 10 bitmap local indexes for that table. We perform some ddl/dml operations on that table in our daily load, which is truncate a specific partition and load data. when we do this, the local bitmap indexes are not becoming unusable. They are in usable status. However, my question is, even though the indexes are not getting unusable, do we always need to incorporate index rebuilding as part of the best practice for range partitioned tables, or use the index rebuilding only when it is required? because index rebuilding takes time, imagine we have 10 local indexes on that table which has large  volume, then it becomes a costly affair for etl.

Please provide me your suggestions or thoughts in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

No a rebuild of local indexes is not required, that is one of the main purpose of an **local** index.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. Could you please elaborate this statement with more details or any documents referring to this.

Answer (score 0):

Local partitioned indexes actually create 'sub index' for each partition, so such 'sub index' can be managed independently from other partitions. And when you truncate partition all its local indexes are truncated either.

Oracle [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin002.htm):

> "You cannot truncate an index partition. However, if local indexes are
>   defined for the table, the ALTER TABLE ... TRUNCATE PARTITION
>   statement truncates the matching partition in each local index."

So when you load data to that partition it recreate local indexes. But statistic on that index could be wrong and optimizer can consider don't use index. So consider gathering statistics from such indexes if you don't do it.

Comment: Thank you for responding and providing the document for reference. Since, the partitioned index also gets truncated for the matching partition. So when I load data to that partition it recreate local index only for the specific partition or recreates entirely?

Comment: @ user1751356 Only for partition.

Comment: is there any document reference for this statement? how do we know that index gets recreated automatically?

Comment: @user1751356 look at this for example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c12parti.htm, http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_global_vs_local_partitioned_indexes.htm.